# Can't pass parameters with CloudPagesURL and Redirect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

On my Cloud Page I have a code that validates form submission and redirects to error Page via:

```
Redirect(CloudPagesURL(301, 'ErrorID', '1'))
```

On error page I'm trying to capture variables passed with either:

```
set @errorID1 = QueryParameter('ErrorID')
set @errorID2 = RequestParameter('ErrorID')
```

Hovewer, no variable is passed and I can't read it with QueryParameter() or RequestParameter() - I'm getting nulls. Am I doing something wrong? CloudPagesURL() function works correctly when I use it in emails and all variables are passed with encoded URL, but when I use it with redirect on pages it fails.

Comment: If you comment out the `Redirect()` and just output the value of `CloudPagesURL(301, 'ErrorID', '1')` what do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the CloudPagesURL() parameters to be buggy -- mostly because it doesn't handle `?` and `&` properly.  You could do something like this:

```
%%[

var @url
set @url = concat(CloudPagesURL(301),"&errorID", "1")

output(concat("<br>redirect url: ", @url))

/* redirect(@url) */

]%%
```

Displaying the URL first should show you what's happening with the parameter delimiters.

Comment: I'm curious. Isn't the general idea that CloudPagesURL can pass variables in an encrypted fashion and then then can simply be retrieved in the CloudPage? :)

Comment: I'm sitting with the same issue actually... tried multiple ways (both concat and with encrypted values). I get the proper qs=[string]&NewsVariable=1 ---> bit I cannot seem to capture this on the cloudpage i Redirect() to. Nothing shows even though url is accurate. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @Adam Spriggs